# dequeuebuffer bufferqueue has no connected producer android 7.0, Camera freeze

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

When i get my app on background using home button, On devices log i can see the error "dequeuebuffer bufferqueue has no connected producer" and camera gets freeze.

Camera will work again when i switch camera to front and back again.

I am not able to solve this error and also not able to get which piece of code causes this issue

I am facing this issue only on the android devices having OS 7.0.
example, Google Pixel, Nexus 5X.